# Does Django have a level of modulation?

Tags: django

The basic Django app contains models and views, however, this structure seems not enough for a complex web app. How can a designer accomplish a certain level of modulation with Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex web app can consist of many different Django apps. A Django app is basically a module centered around a set of URLs and/or models.

Besides that, it's all just Python. You can split off business logic code to any Python modules you want, put views in any modules you want, and turn models.py into a models/ package with submodules (as long as the package's __init__.py imports * from all the submodules, I think).

Answer (score 0):

A Django *project* will often consist of many Django *apps*

When you start to build a "web app" with Django you are creating a *project*... inside this you will structure your code into one or more Django *apps* specific to your project. You will likely make use of a number of 3rd party reusable Django apps as well.

See the tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project